# Session item is getting removed on login in Laravel 5.4

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5

When a guest user puts items into a cart, they are stored in a session like `session('cart', 'item1')`. However once user has logged in, this session gets destroyed for some reason, and I can no longer access it. Why does this session is removed and how do I keep it after user log in?

I tried to dd() the session even before the validation and login attempt takes place, but it still is removed.

```
public function postLogin(Request $request) {
        dd(session('cart'));
        // validate
        // attempt to log in
    }
```

It seems that it gets removed after "post". Is it a normal behavior in Laravel 5 or I'm doing something wrong?

Comment: @Exprator thanks for the replay. can u please tell me whats the alternative way for this.

Comment: @Exprator this is not the right way. Is there any way where we can restrict the session to get destroyed on login.

Comment: @Exprator sorry, that is not the right way to do. thanks

Comment: Just before login check if the pre-login session has the data you need. Assing it to variable(s) and save it to the logged in session.

Comment: @M.Novotny i have already done that. please read the question carefully. anyways i have got the solution thanks.

Comment: @halfer my comment was not rude. i just simply said "read the question carefully" and in the last i said thanks too.

Comment: It's worth noting that thanks after an (apparently) passive-aggressive comment will usually be interpreted as sarcasm, and is sometimes intended to worsen the offence caused. Thus, the presence of (genuine) gratitude does not ameliorate the tone at all, unfortunately. English is complicated `:-)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the solution.

To store the guest user data use the php session like `$_SESSION['cart']='item1'` not Laravel one because Laravel stores its session data in the different file and it flush data of its own.